# Compare Values in a entire Dataframe Row to another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, interaction

Good Morning.

I Have a little Doubt...

I have two dataframes, both of them with 10 columns.

The first one has 5 Rows, lets call it DF 1, and the second one just one Row, lets call it DF B.

What I need is for each Row in DF 1, check if this word is in the Data Frame B.

If it is, i need to save that info in a Variable.

Example DF1:

```
2nd Most Common Venue   3rd Most Common Venue   4th Most Common Venue   5th Most Common Venue   6th                      Most Common Venue  7th Most Common Venue   8th Most Common Venue   9th Most Common Venue   10th Most Common Venue  11st Most Common Venue
0   Brazilian Restaurant    Restaurant  Pizza Place Sandwich Place  Snack Place Gym / Fitness Center            Gym Food Truck  Burger Joint    Plaza
1   Bakery  Pizza Place Beer Garden Music Venue Yoga Studio Fast Food Restaurant    Film Studio Fish & Chips Shop   Fish Market Flea Market
2   Gym Yoga Studio Fried Chicken Joint Farmers Market  Fast Food Restaurant    Film Studio Fish & Chips Shop   Fish Market Flea Market Flower Shop
3   Bar Bakery  Plaza   Burger Joint    Pizza Place Brazilian Restaurant    Gym Restaurant  Gym / Fitness Center    Snack Place
4   Beach   Yoga Studio Farm    Fast Food Restaurant    Film Studio Fish & Chips Shop   Fish Market Flea Market Flower Shop Food
```

DF B:

```
Neighbourhood   1st Most Common Venue   2nd Most Common Venue   3rd Most Common Venue   4th Most Common Venue   5th Most Common Venue   6th Most Common Venue   7th Most Common Venue   8th Most Common Venue   9th Most Common Venue   10th Most Common Venue
0   Moema   Furniture / Home Store  Dessert Shop    Japanese Restaurant Snack Place Pharmacy    Pizza Place Plaza   Middle Eastern Restaurant   Restaurant  Burger Joint
```

In other words, i need to know which row from DF1 has more simillar values to DF B...

The Column order has no difference... The important is to check if that the value is SOMEWHERE in that row... Doesnt need to be in the same column. The Row that has more simmilar values will "Win"...

Does anyone has any idea how to do this?